# What is the manga/manhwa where the main character goes to this portal where there are a bunch of moles?

Tags: story-identification, manga

From what I can remember he went into this portal with moles and that like gold and shiny things and beat the boss then got an item that allowed him to control the servant moles and he farmed items I think.

I think he talked to a hidden dokebi that was watching him and got access to a store before anyone else.

Comment: From what I can think of, is it maybe "The Newbie Is Too Strong"? I don't think that's very close to what you said, but it's the closest thing I can think of with "Moles". Probably not that, to be fair.